# Completely crashed and logs

Tags: crash, log

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04. My PC just completely crashed(neither ctrl+alt+f3 or REISUB work).
I can only find this in the system logs. Other logs are output 15mins before crashing. I'd like to know what does this mean.

```
Jun 25 20:44:32 t480s kernel: [ 5771.643336] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe A (start=346557 end=346558) time 331 us, min 1073, max 1079, scanline start 1070, end 1093
```

[Here are the GNOME extensions I'm using](https://ibb.co/nyyrqT)

Comment: It's an error against your Intel video subsystem. Probably harmless. Probably related to the kernel. Are you running the standard 18.04 kernel? When you say "crashed", explain more. Are you getting more error messages on screen? How old is your PC?

Comment: @heynnema standard Ubuntu 18.04, my laptop comes with i7-8550u and 16GB ram. It crashed(completely freeze, can not get into the virtual terminal) when I watching the movie, no error messages on screen.

Comment: Have you added any GNOME extensions?

Comment: @heynnema I use some, are they dangerous? https://ibb.co/nyyrqT

Comment: One of them could be causing your problem. Give me a list of what you have installed and I'll take a look. Add the list info to your question (not in the comments) please.

Comment: @heynnema Actually, I added a picture in the former comment.

Comment: Ah, I missed that link. You have a lot of extensions, and I don't see **Ubuntu Dock**. At this point, turn **OFF ALL** extensions, reboot, and see if the problem has gone away. If so, enable **ONE** extension at a time until it fails, and that's probably the bad one. Also, show me what's in /var/crash. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema there are a empty file `.lock` and `_opt_google_chrome_chrome.1000.crash` in the /var/crash.

Comment: I can not try the GNOME extensions one by one, my PC doesn't crash that often, it will take months to test all extensions.

Comment: If you turn off all of the GNOME extensions, it should take no time to see if your crashes go away, and then you'll at least be on the right path knowing that you've found the cause. You could also run memtest.